# What do these declarations mean in my .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am a newb to PHP.  Can anyone tell me what each line does here.  Do I need this?  It is giving me errors

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /~([^/]+)/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /~%1/rewrite.php?p=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /~([^/]+)/?
RewriteRule ^index\.php?(.*)$ /~%1/rewrite.php?p=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
#there is no ~ character in the URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) ./rewrite.php?p=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php?(.*)$ ./rewrite.php?p=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
#WJ-180 fix
RewriteRule ^resume\.php?(.*)$ ./rewrite.php?p=resume\.php$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP, this is an Apache config question. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer: These declarations rewrite every request to a `rewrite.php` file.

The more comprehensive answer: The `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives are from the [Apache module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and provide a rule based URL rewrite mechanism.

It seems that these rules are intended to rewrite every request to a `rewrite.php` file, either in a specific directory (`/~`*foobar*`/rewrite.php`) or in the root (`/rewrite.php`).

Answer (score 3):

If you are new, please read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html, it is explained very nicely.

*p.s.* Your title "What do these declarations mean in my PHP .htaccess file?" is incorrect, .htacces is not php file.

Answer (score 2):

These say

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

"Only use the following rule if the request does not match an existing file or directory."

Answer (score 0):

Those are [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) configuration entries.

Answer (score 0):

It an Apache mod_rewrite rule. Unless you are using some sort of framework you probably don't need it. See Apache mod_rewrite for more info.